Reading file data in a linked list read (input.txt) stores the values in a linked list then returns (output.txt)
I want to Build a C file handling program that  reads in values from an input file (input.txt), stores the values in a
linked list array for the processing then outputs the result to an output file
(output.txt).
this is the input txt the program should read
100000 (Initial Target),
{
  {[2023,
    {[month,    revenue,    expense],
     [9,        20000,      22000], 
     [10,       22000,      22000],  
     [11,       26000,      23000],  
     [12,       40000,      22000]}
  ]},
  {[2024,
    {[month,    revenue,    expense],
     [1,        30000,      22000],    
     [2,        40000,      22000],    
     [3,        80000,      25000]}
  ]}
}

this is the output.txt
it should use data from the input.txt and arrange it in this format in the output.txt file

2023
month revenue   expense    Profit    Diff-to-Target
9      20000    22000     -2000     -80000
10     22000    22000       0        -18000
11     26000    23000       3000     -18000
12      40000  22000       18000     -12000
2024
month revenue expense    Profit     Diff-to-Target
1      30000    22000    8000      -50000
2      40000    22000    18000    -20000
3      80000   25000     55000     0

This is the code I used

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define a structure to hold monthly financial data
struct MonthData {
    int month;
    int revenue;
    int expense;
    int profit;
    int diff_to_target;
    struct MonthData* next;
};

// Function to calculate profit and difference to target for each month
void calculateProfitAndDiff(struct MonthData *head) {
    struct MonthData *current = head;
    int prev_target = 0;

    while (current != NULL) {
        current->profit = current->revenue - current->expense;
        current->diff_to_target = current->revenue * 2 - prev_target;
        prev_target = current->revenue * 2;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *output_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (input_file == NULL || output_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening files.");
        return 1;
    }

    struct MonthData *head = NULL;
    struct MonthData *prev = NULL;
    char line[100];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file)) {
        if (line[0] == '{') {
            // Read year
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file);
            int year;
            sscanf(line, "{[%d", &year);

            // Read month data
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file) && line[0] != '}') {
                struct MonthData *new_month = malloc(sizeof(struct MonthData));
                sscanf(line, "[%d, %d, %d]", &new_month->month, &new_month->revenue, &new_month->expense);
                new_month->next = NULL;

                if (head == NULL) {
                    head = new_month;
                } else {
                    prev->next = new_month;
                }
                prev = new_month;
            }

            // Calculate profit and difference to target
            calculateProfitAndDiff(head);

            // Write results to output file
            fprintf(output_file, "%d\n", year);
            fprintf(output_file, "month revenue expense Profit Diff-to-Target\n");
            struct MonthData *current = head;
            while (current != NULL) {
                fprintf(output_file, "%d %d %d %d %d\n", current->month, current->revenue, current->expense, current->profit, current->diff_to_target);
                current = current->next;
            }
            fprintf(output_file, "\n");

            // Free memory allocated for month data
            struct MonthData *temp;
            while (head != NULL) {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp);
            }
            head = NULL;
            prev = NULL;
        }
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);

    return 0;
}


this is what the output txt contains it is giving me random numbers. Can someone tell me what is causing the output to be random and how I can fix it
4202864
month revenue expense Profit Diff-to-Target
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 15073664
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0
7540672 7536832 0 7536832 0


Why a linked list instead of an array? Are you just practicing the use of linked lists?

The Read month data loop doesn't skip over the {[month,    revenue,    expense], lines.

The format string "[%d, %d, %d]" needs a space at the beginning to skip over the indentation.

The Read month data loop should stop when it gets to the ]} line.

I haven't even looked at the linked list code. You need to start by making sure you're actually reading the file properly. Check the return value of sscanf().

It's an assignment and the lecturer told us we can only use linked list. I implemented the changes you suggested and used sscanf() and found out the program wasn't able to read the txt due to the {[month,    revenue,    expense], lines. ]} and other lines . I'll try to modify it now and tell you if there's any other error. Thanks for the feedback

@arfneto The node is the linked list. It's like CONS in Lisp -- there's no separate wrapper type for the list, you just use a pointer to the first node.

@barmar, I am sure it is. As I said, the model is not good (my opinion, for sure). It is clear that it can be done this way, just it is not a good one. There will be loose pointers everywhere, the will be no metadata... Hard to reuse, a pain to use more than one list, hard to test... A linked list is a (possibly empty) collection of nodes. The nodes points to or contain a unit of data. A container, like other ds.

@arfneto Since I've been programming Lisp longer than C, I don't find anything wrong with the model....

@Barmar it is not really wrong. Any container (C++ naming( or collection (java naming) is a collection of nodes. Be it a stack, a queue, a dequeue, a map, a set whatever. And they have metadata. As the model goes away from this, the code gets harder to use, maintain and reuse. As an example, pointers for head and tail and a size count must be inside the list. It is the principle of encapsulation.

@arfneto I'm not saying it's the best way to implement it, but it is a valid way. Saying "you do not even have a linked list" is wrong. The linked list is represented by the head pointer, which can either point to a node or be NULL. These are just different abstractions.

@barmar you are right. I will rephrase it. you do not even have an abstraction for a linked list, only a node-lke structure.

Your model is not good. You do not even have an abstraction for a linked list, only for a node-like thing. And you are mixing things in code. All of it makes it harder to get the job done, for the code to be reused, or even for it to be tested. Follow what @Barmar said, for example, and assure at least that the data is coming ok. Read the manual. sscanf returns a value for a reason. Use it.

@arfneto Source code is not likely to make sense, since the style is so different from conventional languages. Try starting with the wikipedia page.

What is the question?

I don't understand the values in the last column of the expected output. What do they represent? Why is the value in that column changing in the second row when the revenue and expense is equal?

@trincot the last value is a running balance, starting with the initial target...

It's been two days; I don't even remember what this was about.
